# Trait with default implementation and required struct member

Tags: rust, traits

I have a rust trait which is supposed to add a value to vector. In order for the `add_job` function to be working, it must be made sure that the vector exists when the trait is implemented for a concrete struct.

The following code fails of course, because jobs is never implemented. It's just there to demonstrate my intention:

```rust
trait Person {
    // default implementation of add job
    fn add_job(&self, job: String) {
        self.jobs.push(job)
    }
}

struct Customer {
    // add_job is used as default implementation 
    // provided by trait
}

impl Person for Customer {
    // some stuff
}

fn main() {
    let mut george = Customer {};
    george.add_job("programmer".to_string());
}
```

Is there a way to have a trait which also provides struct members?

Propably not, but what would be the "rustful" way to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Traits can't provide or require struct fields. Though there is an [RFC (#1546)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1546) about allowing fields in traits. However, there isn't any unstable features allowing this (yet?).

---

You can still simplify what you're trying to do though. I've taken the liberty to rename and change your trait, to be able to provide more thorough examples.

Let's consider that we have a `Jobs` trait. Which defines various methods, that all requires the `jobs: Vec<String>` field.

```rust
trait Jobs {
    fn add_job(&mut self, job: String);
    fn clear_jobs(&mut self);
    fn count_jobs(&self) -> usize;
}
```

---

### Using a macro

One solution could be to use a `macro`, which implements all those methods.

```rust
macro_rules! impl_jobs_with_field {
    ($($t:ty),+ $(,)?) => ($(
        impl Jobs for $t {
            fn add_job(&mut self, job: String) {
                self.jobs.push(job);
            }

            fn clear_jobs(&mut self) {
                self.jobs.clear();
            }

            fn count_jobs(&self) -> usize {
                self.jobs.len()
            }
        }
    )+)
}
```

Then you can easily reuse the code, by using the macro.

```rust
struct Person {
    jobs: Vec<String>,
}

struct Customer {
    jobs: Vec<String>,
}

impl_jobs_with_field!(Person);
impl_jobs_with_field!(Customer);
// or
impl_jobs_with_field!(Person, Customer);
```

---

### Using a second `HasJobs` trait

Another solution could be to introduce a second `HasJobs` trait. Then you can use a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods) for `Jobs` if a type implements `HasJobs`.

```rust
trait HasJobs {
    fn jobs(&self) -> &[String];
    fn jobs_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<String>;
}

impl<T: HasJobs> Jobs for T {
    fn add_job(&mut self, job: String) {
        self.jobs_mut().push(job);
    }

    fn clear_jobs(&mut self) {
        self.jobs_mut().clear();
    }

    fn count_jobs(&self) -> usize {
        self.jobs().len()
    }
}
```

Now `HasJobs` still needs to be implemented for all your types. But if `Jobs` has a significant amount of methods. Then implementing `HasJobs` is a lot easier to deal with. Which we can also do using a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_has_jobs {
    ($($t:ty),+ $(,)?) => ($(
        impl HasJobs for $t {
            fn jobs(&self) -> &[String] {
                &self.jobs
            }

            fn jobs_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<String> {
                &mut self.jobs
            }
        }
    )+)
}
```

Then once again, you just do:

```rust
struct Person {
    jobs: Vec<String>,
}

struct Customer {
    jobs: Vec<String>,
}

impl_has_jobs!(Person);
impl_has_jobs!(Customer);
// or
impl_has_jobs!(Person, Customer);
```

---

## Using `Deref` and `DerefMut`

Lastly, if `Customer` is always a `Person`, then you could change `Person` into a `struct` and use composition, i.e. add `person: Person` to `Customer` (and other types).

So first, `impl Jobs for Person`:

```rust
struct Person {
    jobs: Vec<String>,
}

impl Jobs for Person {
    fn add_job(&mut self, job: String) {
        self.jobs.push(job);
    }

    fn clear_jobs(&mut self) {
        self.jobs.clear();
    }

    fn count_jobs(&self) -> usize {
        self.jobs.len()
    }
}
```

Then now you can use [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) to dereference `Customer` to `Person`. Thus all `Person`'s methods are available directly through `Customer`.

However, this solution only *works* if you only have one "trait", i.e. you can only `Deref` `Customer` to `Person`. You wouldn't be able to also `Deref` `Customer` to `SomethingElse`.

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

struct Customer {
    person: Person,
}

impl Deref for Customer {
    type Target = Person;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.person
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Customer {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.person
    }
}
```

Comment: As a comment, there are some RFCs to allow fields on traits

Comment: I was already looking for it. But thanks for mentioning anyways! :)

Comment: Great Answer, more than I had hoped for!

Comment: Thanks for this answer because of its references! Been coding in Rust for at least a year now, coding it in production as well, but I just found out what *Blanket Implementations* are. Keep seeing it in documentation, it makes me understand how a type functions more, but no idea how to implement it myself. And IT IS AMAZING KNOWING ABOUT THIS. Will refactor a lot of my codes.